# Why do table names have to be plural in Laravel?

Tags: database, laravel

I noticed that whenever I create a class using database information in Laravel, the table name must be plural. Why is this?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a requirement, but logically it makes sense. You do not have a database of `post`, it's a database of `posts`. Or, a database of `user`, there are many `users`

Comment: I see, that makes sense. But in laravel, the link between the code and the table cannot be made unless the table name is plural.

Comment: Just to follow on from this, if you have a company, the plural of this is companies. Eloquent caters for this, much like it's helper function `str_plural` - https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-str-plural

Comment: I believe in your model you can override this and use whatever table name you like, if you have a Users model you can add `protected $table = 'user';`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

They don't have to be plural. To make things easy, by default, Eloquent assumes that, if you have a model `User`, your database table for it will be `users`. However, if you want to have another name for your table, you can specify custom tables for your models, by defining a `table` property. For ex:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'user';

    ...
}
```

This will tell Eloquent to use the table `user` on your database when working with the model `User`.

Comment: Good Answer has come finally. I was searching for this one

Comment: Any way to set this to the default behaviour of `Laravel`? This annoyance shouldn't even exist!

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov check my answer below to see how you can do that.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to the accepted answer and one of its comments… You can make your own Model class that all your other models will extend from instead of the Laravel one and set the naming to singular there in the `getTable()` function.

For instance, mine looks like this:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class BaseModel extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the table associated with the model.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTable()
    {
        return $this->table ?? Str::snake(class_basename($this));
    }
}
```

And all your other models just `extends BaseModel` instead of `Model` and will automatically use singular table names by default.